# Obtaining a foreign key Id to post related data

Tags: asp.net

I'm building a one to many 2 table relationship in which I will have a 'sessions' table that contains multiple entries of notes from a 'notes' table.

I am getting null values for my 'SessionId' when trying to use an HttpPost method to post notes to a specific session.

**Model**

```
public class Sessions
{
    [Key]
    public int SessionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Session Name: ")]
    public string SessionName { get; set; }
}

public class Notes
{
    [Key]
    public int NotesId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual int SessionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SessionId")]
    public virtual Sessions Session { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class TheDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Sessions> Sessions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Notes> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class HomeVM
{
    public List<Sessions> SessionList { get; set; }
    public Sessions NewSession { get; set; }
    public Notes SessionId { get; set; }
}

public class NotesVM
{

    public List<Notes> NotesList { get; set; }
    public Notes NewNote { get; set; }
}
```

**Create Notes View "Index"**

```
@model NoteTakingv2.Models.NotesVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Notes Session";
}

<h2>Notes Session</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NewNote.SessionId)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NewNote.Text)
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <p>Notes</p>
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var i in Model.NotesList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @i.Text
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**NotesController**

```
public class NotesController : Controller
    {
        TheDbContext db = new TheDbContext();

        public ActionResult Index(int sessionId)
        {
            NotesVM model = new NotesVM();
            model.NewNote = new Notes { SessionId = sessionId };
            model.NotesList = db.Notes.Where(n => n.SessionId == sessionId).ToList();

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "NotesId,SessionId,Text")]Notes model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Notes.Add(model);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

I'm unsure where I'm going wrong, but it must be that I'm not properly obtaining the "SessionId" when posting.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle it - Inspect the request make sure it's posting the values correctly.
If it is indeed posting correctly, try changing the action parameter.

Personally I never allow the model binder to create an instance of an entity class - I always have a separation between input, output and entity models.

Try creating a new model for the input parameter, removing the Bind attribute and see what happens.

Happy debugging!

Comment: Thank you!  I will do my best!